# What does 'ground this thing out' means?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this senior defense official means by saying this: “He is signaling that he’s trying to ground this thing out,” a senior defense official said in an interview.

Source: https://www.nytimes.com/2022/09/20/us/politics/biden-gas-russia-europe.html

Comment: The NYT is behind a paywall, so I can't read it in context. [Here's the same text](https://influentialmag.co.uk/business/u-s-shores-up-ukraine-support-as-energy-crisis-in-europe-looms/) from a different source. Personally I think the cited official is mixing up his metaphoric usages. Probably he meant ***put it to bed*** (be done with it, conclusively *finish* it).

Comment: ...or it could be an American baseball reference: ***to ground [out]*** - *To hit (a ground ball); to bat (a hit) along the ground.* But I've no idea what that might mean *figuratively* in the cited context.